# RVM Not Changing Ruby Version on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, macos-sierra

I'm trying to change my ruby versions on Mac and even though it says its on the right ruby version (2.3.4), it still doesn't work.

Example output:

```
:~ my_username$ cd my_project_name
:my_project_name my_username$ which ruby
/Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby
:my_project_name my_username$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-darwin16]
:my_project_name my_username$ bundle install
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.4
:my_project_name my_username$
```

And RVM list, and then attempting to bundle install for my project:

```
:my_project_name my_username$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.3.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

:my_project_name my_username$ bundle install
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.4
:my_project_name my_username$
```

As you can see, I have both 2.3.4 installed and set to the current ruby version but it doesn't detect it in my directory. I've closed and retried several times in a new terminal window.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, but in my case I can't even install bundler

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i had bundler installed before RVM was setup. Ran `gem install bundler` and now I'm able to bundle install and everything works fine.